# Issues with building any C++ on Sublime Text 3

Tags: c++, build, mingw, sublimetext3

So I'm trying to build a C++ program on Sublime Text 3 but I keep getting a variety of issues. I've tried numerous video and web tutorials and have all failed me, so please don't recommend me any. Here's what I've done:

I am building with build file `CPP.sublime-build`:

```
{
 "cmd":["bash", "-c", "g++ -std=c++14 -Wall '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"],
 "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
 "working_dir": "${file_path}",
 "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
 "variants":
 [
   {
     "name": "Run",
     "cmd":["bash", "-c", "g++ -std=c++14 '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
   }
 ]
}
```

I've installed MinGW, and have edited my environmental PATH variable to include `C:\MinGW\bin`.

I have `HelloWorld.cpp` below, in directory `C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\C++`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::cout <<  "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to build this file (Ctrl-B) in Sublime Text, however, I get this long error:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['bash', '-c', "g++ -std=c++   -Wall 'C:\\Users\\kevin\\Desktop\\C++\\HelloWorld.cpp' -o 'C:\\Users\\kevin\\Desktop\\C++/HelloWorld' && 'C:\\Users\\kevin\\Desktop\\C++/HelloWorld'"]]
[dir: C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\C++]
[path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
[Finished]
```

Building with the built-in `C++ Single File` generates another error:

```
Access is denied.
[Finished in 2.6s with exit code 1]
```

Additional details: Running Windows 10, x64 based PC.

Any ideas?

EDIT: DO NOT recommend me Visual Studio- it works but I'm a minimalist and hate it.

Comment: Do you get similar results using the `C++ Single File.sublime-build` that ships with Sublime?

Comment: As an addition, `g++ HelloWorld.cpp` won't display anything in the console unless the compiler finds an error or something to warn about, so not seeing anything means that your code compiles without errors.

Comment: @OdatNurd Oh yeah, forgot to mention that. I get another error, `Access is denied. [Finished in 2.6s with exit code 1]`.

Comment: Also, trying `HelloWorld.exe` in the command prompt gives the same error: `Access is denied`.

Comment: In your first error message it says `C:\\Users\\kevin\\Desktop\\C++/HelloWorld`, it looks like it's puttin the linux default, using `/HelloWorld` at the end instead of `\\HelloWorld.exe`. Not sure it that is the cause of the problem, but it looks suspicious.

Comment: @super thanks, but do you have any actual suggestions on how to act on that?

Comment: If you are using Windows 10 with Powershell by default, take into account that your .sublime-build may be obsolete (i.e., the "&&" no longer works)